# Generating file process updates in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, asynchronous, service

On button click I would like to call my Service to query database and generate csv file and return in back to user. This process is long running (can take up to 40 sec) I would like not to block user . I would lik to create Progress page, where user can tack a progress of report generation:

**My idea is:**

Take input from user and submit createReport request to the Service. 
Do not wait for the response, return report ID back to user.
The new tab will be open, where user can monitor the status of report generation
User can check the report page to see the status of his request
When request is ready - downloading of report will start in browser.

**I would like to have smth like this:**

a.  Controller method that save the file and return file id.
After that, in this contorller  the new thread will call Service and write data to the given file
b.  Controller method that show report's status using request params - fileId
 Check if file generated or not
If file is generated - write file to the  HttpServletResponse response

Question is:
Where should I store file ID and how to connect file ID and file itself? (cache? database?)

How can I check report status? I think about sending AJAX request every 1-2 sec?

Any ideas and recommendations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, you can create a servlet to respond with CSV file download. Consider the following process:

On button click open new tab with url (append url with reportId or so)

```
window.open('/downloadCSV/15646', '_blank');
```

And then write a servlet for this downloading operation

```
  @RequestMapping(path = "/downloadCSV/{reportId}", method = 
    RequestMethod.GET)
        public void getCSV(@PathVariable String reportId, HttpServletRequest 
         request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

            byte[] fileContent;

           //write your logic or call service to generate csv report and get 
           bytes of file

                response.setContentType("provide content type");
                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                out.write(fileContent);
                out.flush();
            return;
        }
```

this will download the file in opened tab